# Area of the perimeter of a rectangle & irregular shape with some thickness?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the area of an edge of both a rectangle and an irregular shape, an "H" shape. Like this:

https://www.printableparadise.com/letters/printable-letter-h-outline.png

All measurements are known. **Firstly, is there a mathematical term for this shape?** Googling "area of edge", "area of thickness", "area of perimeter", etc produces poor results.

**What is the best way to perform this calculation?** I tried two ways, and achieved different results. Say I have a figure that is 11 cm wide by 2 cm tall that has a perimeter 0.3175 cm thick.

First way, I tried to calculate using the measurements of the edge. Essentially, I am looking at the edge around the rectangle as four separate rectangles of length equal to the rectangles respective width/height and then a width equal to the thickness of the rectangle. Considering these four rectangle overlap, I reduce the length of two of the rectangles by the thickness of the edge, which should have each rectangle no longer overlap.

$$
(Thickness*(Width-(Thickness*2))*2)+((Thickness*Height)*2)
$$

Which came out to 7.852cm^2.

Next, I took the area of the rectangle then subtracted from it the area of the smaller rectangle made by cutting away the edging.

$$
(Width*Height)-((Width-Thickness)*(Height-Thickness))
$$

My result is 4.027 cm^2.

**Why are these two methods getting different results?** Are my formulas incorrect and these results should be the same? Or is one method incorrect over vs. the other?

Comment: In your second method, the inner rectangle to be subtracted should have an area

$$((\text{Width} - \text{Thickness} \times 2) \times (\text{Height} - \text{Thickness} \times 2))$$